# Need to Automate the copying of an attachment in order to push to Splunk

Tags: powershell, exchange-server, powershell-3.0, splunk, exchange-server-2013

I'm trying to figure out a way to copy an attachment from a specific Mailbox to a folder on our exchange server so it can then be pushed to splunk.

The attachment in question is a log file generated by a cloud based application - our auditors gave us the surprise requirement that this log file now needs to be automatically uploaded into splunk (previously automated email reports were adequate).

The Exchange server is a on-prem 2013, the Splunk is on prem also. I've dabeled in VBA for an outlook script, but I dont want to corner myself into making sure I have a dedicated outlook install for it - I would like it to just be an automated task or scheduled script that runs on the exchange server.

I'm currently playing with the search-mailbox feature in exchange shell - but haven't found any functionality that looks like it can help me.

I already have the local hot-folder for splunk configured, that was the easy part.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You may consider using EWS, see [Explore the EWS Managed API, EWS, and web services in Exchange](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/explore-the-ews-managed-api-ews-and-web-services-in-exchange) for more information.

The following code example shows how to get an `EmailMessage` object by using the `Bind` method, then iterate through the attachment collection and call the `FileAttachment.Load` or `ItemAttachment.Load` method on each attachment as appropriate. Each file attachment is saved to the `C:\temp\` folder, and each item attachment is loaded into memory. For information about how to save an item attachment, see [Save an attached email by using the EWS Managed API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/how-to-get-attachments-by-using-ews-in-exchange#bk_saveitemattach).

```
public static void GetAttachmentsFromEmail(ExchangeService service, ItemId itemId)
{
    // Bind to an existing message item and retrieve the attachments collection.
    // This method results in an GetItem call to EWS.
    EmailMessage message = EmailMessage.Bind(service, itemId, new PropertySet(ItemSchema.Attachments));
    // Iterate through the attachments collection and load each attachment.
    foreach (Attachment attachment in message.Attachments)
    {
        if (attachment is FileAttachment)
        {
            FileAttachment fileAttachment = attachment as FileAttachment;
            // Load the attachment into a file.
            // This call results in a GetAttachment call to EWS.
            fileAttachment.Load("C:\\temp\\" + fileAttachment.Name);
           
            Console.WriteLine("File attachment name: " + fileAttachment.Name);
        }
        else // Attachment is an item attachment.
        {
            ItemAttachment itemAttachment = attachment as ItemAttachment;
            // Load attachment into memory and write out the subject.
            // This does not save the file like it does with a file attachment.
            // This call results in a GetAttachment call to EWS.
            itemAttachment.Load();
            Console.WriteLine("Item attachment name: " + itemAttachment.Name);
        }
    }
}
```

As for PowerShell, you may find the [Exchange Server PowerShell (Exchange Management Shell)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/exchange/exchange-management-shell?view=exchange-ps) section in MSDN helpful.

Comment: I'll give EWS a shot, will post an update when I have one. Thanks!

Comment: Do you know  if an EWS script would be possible without having a plain text password in it? I dont know much about EWS, but the few examples Im finding that same relevant include a plain text password - that may be a deal breaker for us.